# Error : no command namde "listener" when trying to install "django-tracking"

Tags: python, android, django, debian

while Trying to install 'django-tracking' library with pip, easy install and get

Using mobile android ..
JuiceSSH app on Android..
Latest version of Django(4.1.7), pip3, and python (3.9)
Debian server and Apache web server.

Hello guys, i am almost new to django and i am working on some demo website, i want to track the visitors number, where they come from, and other things, so i tried to use 'django-tracking' library..

This error is appear to me when i run the command:

`Pip install django-tracking`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p38Jk.jpg)

It seems that the error appears twice, then it install 'django-tracking' version 0.2

Then i tried this:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git
```

I got the same issue:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbgqG.jpg)

When i run :

`

pip freez

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0ryP.jpg)

The listiner is installed but no thing called **listeners** with S ..

Same issue with `easy_install django-tracking`

Note that i use mobile android to do everything and the error is on web server Apache..

I want solution please...

Thanks..

Comment: Update newer ver for pip.  py -m pip install django-tracking

Comment: Same error it install another version of django-tracking

Comment: Didn't you upgrade for pip?

Comment: Yes i upgrade pip and this error is appear:

Comment: pip install django-tracking-analyzer It is latest version.

Comment: Okay it works successfully, but i want to know if it is the same library?

Comment: I don\t use djanjo/ It iis same library with newer version.